# AppStoreConnect says TestFlight build is "ready to submit" but I can't get it to beta test

Tags: ios, react-native, app-store, app-store-connect, testflight

I've been using TestFlight on my app for a while, and recently pushed my first actual build to the app store. Now I'm on a subsequent build, and am trying to push to TestFlight. It goes into "ready to submit" mode, and nothing gets sent to the internal testers in the group I've added to the build.

Does anyone know how to approach this?

Comment: Review isn't required for internal testing (emails that are part of your development team). If you add an external tester then it will prompt you to submit for review.

Comment: are your internal testers `App Store Connect Users`? if so, they should have received the update.